# How to insert data from inputs to a class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a class and I want to insert data to it from two inputs. Then, I want to press a button and show the data of the class. Can someone help me please? I cannot make it work...

```
<input type="text",id="1",value="">
<input type="text",id="2",value="">
<button onclick="document.write(person)">show</button>

<script>
    person = {
        name:""
        lastname:""
    };

    person.name=document.getElementById('1');
    person.lastname=document.getElementById('2');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood your question, but here is a [start fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/s3z2vn98/1/)

```
<input type="text" id="1" value=""> <br>
<input type="text" id="2" value=""><br>
<input type="text" id="3" value=""><br>
<button onclick="javascript:show()">Show</button>

function show()
{
  document.getElementById( "3" ).value = document.getElementById( "1" ).value + " " + document.getElementById( "2" ).value
}
```

After this update, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/s3z2vn98/2/) looks more closer to your requirement

```
function show()
{
  var person = {
    firstName : document.getElementById( "1" ).value,
    lastName : document.getElementById( "2" ).value
  }
  document.getElementById( "3" ).value = JSON.stringify( person );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" id="1" value="">
<input type="text" id="2" value="">
<button onclick="show()">show</button>

<script>
person={
 name:"",
 lastname:""
};
function show() {
 person.name=document.getElementById('1').value;
 person.lastname=document.getElementById('2').value;  
 document.write(JSON.stringify(person));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

1. There is `typo` mistake in
   `person = {
       name:"",      // missing comma here.
       lastname:""
   };`
2. you want the updated value of `person` when you click on it so make a function and put `person.name=document.getElementById('1');
   person.lastname=document.getElementById('2')`
   in that function

```html
<input type="text" id="1" value="">
<input type="text" id="2" value="">
<button onclick="show()">show</button>

<script>
person={
 name:"",
 lastname:""
};
function show() {
 person.name=document.getElementById('1').value;
 person.lastname=document.getElementById('2').value;  
 document.write(JSON.stringify(person));
}
</script>
```